# Laravel system info

Tags: php, laravel-4, composer-php

Is it possible to automatically display system info of Laravel (such as laravel version, installed dependency, dependency version and etc) onto the webpage?

Thank you.

Comment: I'm not sure about the dependency info but you can use this to get version number - $app::VERSION

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The info about stuff managed by Composer is returned with `composer show -i` (show installed dependencies) from the command line.

I'm pretty sure you should be able to include the composer code directly, ask the same question and avoid the command line, but I have yet to fine out how.

The other method might be to load the contents of `composer.lock` or `vendor/composer/installed.json`, parse and display them. Be prepared to experience changing file formats, because that is no official API, but a shortcut.